# Issue installing SQL Server 2012 SP4 in a cluster - missing ‘vc_red.msi’

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, errors, service-pack

Installed SQL Sever 2012 SP4 (from SP3) on one node of a two-node SQL Server cluster without issue. On the other node it is exiting out of the install with the following message:

> The required MSI package 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Update Cache\KB4018073\ServicePack\redist\VisualStudioShell\VC10SP1\vc_red.msi' doesn't exist.

**Full Log Summary**

> Overall summary:   Final result:                  The patch installer
>   has failed to update the following instance: MSSQLSERVER. To determine
>   the reason for failure, review the log files.   Exit code (Decimal):
>   -2068709375   Start time:                    2018-01-11 19:09:04   End time:                      2018-01-11 19:11:32   Requested action:
>   Patch
>
> Instance MSSQLSERVER overall summary:   Final result:
>   The patch installer has failed to update the shared features. To
>   determine the reason for failure, review the log files.   Exit code
>   (Decimal):           -2068709375   Exit facility code:            1202
>   Exit error code:               1   Exit message:                  The
>   required MSI package 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Update
>   Cache\KB4018073\ServicePack\redist\VisualStudioShell\VC10SP1\vc_red.msi'
>   doesn't exist.   Start time:                    2018-01-11 19:10:24
>   End time:                      2018-01-11 19:11:27   Requested action:
>   Patch   Exception help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.7001.0&EvtType=0xB34122F7%400xF762992B%401202%401&EvtType=0xB34122F7%400xF762992B%401202%401
>
> Cluster properties:   Machine name: USPANSQLC2   Product
>   Instance             Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured   SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for
>   Search 1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality Services
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012
>   Management Tools - Basic                 1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Management Tools - Complete              1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools Connectivity                1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools SDK                         1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   SQL Server Data Tools                    1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Integration Services                     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes
>
> Machine name: USPANSQLC1   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured   SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     Yes        Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER
>   SQL Server Replication
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     Yes        Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER
>   Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     Yes        Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER
>   Data Quality Services
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     Yes        Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Management Tools - Basic                 1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Management Tools - Complete              1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools Connectivity                1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools SDK                         1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   SQL Server Data Tools                    1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Integration Services                     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.4.7001.0     No         Yes
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  USPANSQLC2
>   Machine processor count:       8   OS version:
>   Future Windows Version   OS service pack:                  OS region: 
>   United Kingdom   OS language:                   English (United
>   States)   OS architecture:               x64   Process architecture:
>   64 Bit   OS clustered:                  Yes
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured   SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for
>   Search 1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality Services
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     Yes
>   Yes          SQL Server 2012
>   Management Tools - Basic                 1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Management Tools - Complete              1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools Connectivity                1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Client Tools SDK                         1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   SQL Server Data Tools                    1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes          SQL
>   Server 2012
>   Integration Services                     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   11.3.6020.0     No         Yes
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2012    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012   Type: 
>   RTM   Version:                       11   SPLevel:
>   4   KBArticle:                     KB4018073   KBArticleHyperlink:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4018073   PatchType:
>   SP   AssociatedHotfixBuild:         0   Platform:
>   x64   PatchLevel:                    11.4.7001.0   ProductVersion:
>   11.0.2100.60   GDRReservedRange:              11.0.2200.60:11.0.2300.00;11.0.3100.0:11.0.3299.0;11.0.5300.0:11.0.5499.0;11.0.6200.0:11.0.6499.0;11.0.7200.0:11.0.7399.0   Installation location:
>   c:\ee6e266550dfbd12854def39ded067\x64\setup\
>
> Updated product edition:   Instance             Edition
>   MSSQLSERVER          Enterprise
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Patch
>   ALLINSTANCES:                  false   CLUSTERPASSIVE:
>   false   CONFIGURATIONFILE:                ENU:
>   false   HELP:                          false
>   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true   INDICATEPROGRESS:
>   false   INSTANCEID:                       INSTANCENAME:
>      QUIET:                         false   QUIETSIMPLE:
>   false   SQMREPORTING:                  false   UIMODE:
>   Normal   X86:                           false
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> There are no scenario-specific rules.
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20180111_190854\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

**My attempts**

Aiming to solve the issue, I've tried:

- to download a new SP4 .exe to no avail.
- copying the exe to a local drive on the server. Nothing doing either.
- downloading the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 redist it seems to be asking for and creating this path, but it makes no difference.

**Other considerations**

I'd rather not uninstall SP4 from the other node, as usually the solutions to these types of weird issues are resolvable.

This is not a production setup, so I'm not under any particular pressure to urgently fix this. Right now the problem node has been stopped in the cluster.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Please share complete [SQL Server installation logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files) on shared drive and post the link here. Look out logs for the date you upgraded to SP4

Comment: I've added the full summary from the log @Shanky

Comment: Since nobody has replied to this, I thought I would provide an update. The issue is now with Microsoft Support who have taken a copy of the event logs and are looking into it. When resolved I will provide an answer.

Comment: I am sorry, sometimes I miss to keep track of the threads. It is good that MS is looking at it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this update requires VS Redist 2010 SP1, but it does not contain it in `ServicePack\redist\VisualStudioShell\VC10SP1\`. Instead, it is in folder `redist` inside of package itself.

You can rename it to `.zip`, open it, and there is a `redist` folder. I use `far` file manager with `arclite` plugin so I opened `.exe` file as `.zip`:

[image]

Then copy it to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Update Cache\KB4018073\ServicePack\redist\`

See also: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/05/12/sql-server-error-installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-shell/

Be sure to copy *whole* folder. First time I did not copy `x86` (I use `x64`), and it failed:

```
Error code 1642
Unknown\Absent: {6F8500D2-A80F-3347-9081-B41E71C8592B} - e:\2d2aef5187a4b73e56483f26fc6b\redist\VisualStudioShell\VC10SP1\x86\msp_kb2565063.msp
```

What else you could do is install vs 2010 x64 sp1 manually: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13523